# fontspec and background

Tags: xetex, fontspec, backgrounds

XeLaTeX seems to calculate background positions different from pdflatex.
I want to create a borderframe around a page using the background package. But unfortunately the result compiled with pdflatex (works well) is different from the xelatex's output. Happens when the fontspec package is loaded.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% please uncomment for use with xelatex 
% and compile 2 times:
%\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgContents{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    {\fontsize{172}{72}\selectfont {\textbf pdflatex}}
        \draw [line width=3pt,
        ]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (.3cm,-.3cm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-.3cm,.3cm) $);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

And here the outputs:

[image]

How to solve this? I want to use xelatex.

Comment: fontspec is not relevant. The position if wrong with xelatex even if it is not loaded. It works for me when I remove the overlay option, but it would be interesting to know why ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thank you, I didn't try to remove the overlay option. It works for me, but would be interesting, if there is a solution or explanation.

Comment: background uses tikz itself, the content of the background is in a node. So you have a (overlay) tikzpicture which contains a node which contains a tikzpicture. Such things are imho fragile. It is difficult to shield the inner tikzpicture from code from the outer. I would use eso-pic or atbegshi to place the frame and use background only for more or less normal text.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: wow, thank you. Would you like to write your comment as an answer? So could I accept it.