# backgroundsetup and tikzpicture placement

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, backgrounds

I'm trying to put a tikzpicture on a (titlepage) using background page. Now, if I put some text content instead, it works as expected (centered on page).
But if I use tikzpicture (with a sample rectangle) it looks like the tikzpicture's 0,0 coordinates are at center, not at top left. That's not a big problem except when using page for positioning (i.e. (current page.west) won't work).
Am I missing something obvious? How would I put a border around the page?

This is a sample with hardcoded coordinates that centers my rectangle on page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}

\definecolor{titlepagecolor} {cmyk}{0.6262,0.5157,0.4597,0.3977}

\backgroundsetup{
    placement=center,
    scale=1,
    angle=0,
    opacity=1,
    nodeanchor=center,
    contents={
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \path [fill=titlepagecolor] (-5, -5) rectangle (5, 5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\BgThispage

%\phantom{wbweb}
\end{titlepage}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Update (my output from @Alenanno's code]). I'm using TexStudio/XeLaText on Windows if this matters.
[image: My output from @Alenanno's code]

Update: Looks like an issue with XeLaTex only.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! How do you want the rectangle to appear? Like a frame around the text?

Comment: Did you compile twice without the generated files being deleted in between?

Comment: Not sure, Tex Studio manages that.

Comment: However, I've found out that this is an issue only with XeLaTex, other guys work as exepected (PDFLaTex, LaTex and LuaLaTex). Interesting though.

Comment: I just had to retypeset a document from 2012 (it worked then) that needed to be typeset in 2019 with `xelatex`. I encountered the same misaligned background node issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your problem is, `current page.#anchor` should work, and using your code, it worked for me. If you only want to put a frame, then you need to `\draw` a rectangle, as opposed to a `\fill`.

I've made it so that the rectangle will increase its thickness towards the center, if you want to change it. So none of the rectangle goes outside of the page (the light grey border you see is part of the preview of the page in the application).

### Misplacement with `xelatex`

As explained in the question [fontspec and background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283002/4778), the content of `background` is in a node. So you have two solutions:

1. Don't use `background`. After all, you need this in one page only, so enclose the whole `tikzpicture` in a new command called `\mycover`, for example, and then add that to the document.
2. Use the [`eso-pic`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) package, although I've never used this one so you should check the documentation.

I think the first solution is the easiest and fastest to adopt.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor} % these two are not needed (i.e. already loaded) with your current setup
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for lorem ipsum
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,shapes.geometric}

\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{0.6262,0.5157,0.4597,0.3977}

\backgroundsetup{
    placement=center,
    scale=1,
    angle=0,
    opacity=1,
    nodeanchor=center,
    contents={
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            %\path [fill=titlepagecolor] (-5, -5) rectangle (5, 5);
            \draw[titlepagecolor, line width=1cm] 
                ($(current page.north west)+(.5\pgflinewidth,-.5\pgflinewidth)$) rectangle 
                ($(current page.south east)+(-.5\pgflinewidth,.5\pgflinewidth)$);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\BgThispage

%\phantom{wbweb}
\end{titlepage}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've added output generated from your code to original question. Yes, I'd expect your output but somehow I get mine. Note that my rectangle's 0,0 is in center for some reason.

Comment: @MihaMarkic Please see edit. Also, why is the content of your `titlepage` (here represented by a lorem ispum) written after the `titlepage` environment is closed? Should it be inside?

Comment: Looks like mystery is solved.